# Ant design Table dataIndex not working for the when the search option

Tags: typescript, antd

Im using my react type script project for ant **[design 4 table](https://ant.design/components/table/)** for the table search. but table search  `dataIndex` not working , any solution for this?

**[stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d9m4jn?file=index.js)**

```
{
    title: 'My Book',
    dataIndex: 'myBook',
    key: 'myBook',
    ...this.getColumnSearchProps('myBook'),
    render: (text: any, res: any) => <span>{res.myDetails.myBook}</span>,
},
```

here the my **datasource**

```
import {bookDetailDto} from "app/dto/bookDetailDto";
    
export interface BookdetailDto {
    myBook:string,       
    bookDetailDto:bookDetailDto,
}
```

**table**

```
<Table
    columns={this.columns}
    dataSource={this.state.BookdetailDto}
    scroll={{x: 1100, y: 300}}
    size={'small'} onChange={onChange}
    bordered                     
    rowKey={record => record.myBook.toString()}
/>
```

Comment: Are you sure that dot notation work in this case?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Hello there, i tried using `myBook` but same conflict

Comment: Hard to say without reproducable example(

Comment: Are you sure `dataSource` has `myBook` property?

Comment: @captain-yossarian yes i already  added, but my another col search working im using that type `render: text => <a>{text}</a>`

Comment: I think `render` has next signature: `function(text, record, index) {}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226808/discussion-between-core114-and-captain-yossarian).

Comment: @core114 can you share [mwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self-contained%20correct%20example.) and sample data

Comment: @Chandan here the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d9m4jn?file=index.js

Comment: @core114 please check if updated answers helpful

Comment: @core114 what is assigned to `this.state.BookdetailDto` in state

Comment: @core114 is your issue resolved

Comment: @Chandan not yet resolved :(

Comment: @core114 can you update [this](https://pasteboard.co/JJ5Jglw.png) data according to your data

Comment: @Chandan Hi, date is coming to the BookdetailDto to via backend

Comment: @core114 what is the response from backend and how it is assigned to `BookdetailDto` is there any processing in it

Comment: @core114 can you add that sample response in `data` variable

Comment: @Chandan i will update it

Answer (score 0):

```
import {bookDetailDto} from "app/dto/bookDetailDto";

export interface BookdetailDto {
    myBook: string;
    bookDetailDto:bookDetailDto;
}
```

If i layout the data according to `BookdetailDto` interface

```json
[{
  myBook: 'some data',
  bookDetailDto: {
     ...
  }
}]
```

if data is like this then there is no myDetails key then `render` would be like this for `myBook` key

```js
render: (text: any, res: any) => <span>{res.myBook}</span>
```

OR

if data is like this

```
[{
  myDesign: {
    myBook: 'some data',
    bookDetailDto: {
     ...
    }
  }
}]
```

then column definition needs to be changed to

```
[{
    title: 'My Book',
    dataIndex: 'myDesign',
    key: 'myDesign',
    ...this.getColumnSearchProps('myDesign'),
    render: (text: any, res: any) => <span>{res.myDetails.myBook}</span>,
},
```

and render needs to update accordingly.

**Note:** You can confirm by printing `record` in `render` function

Comment: but unfortunately my data is coming to a using ~myDetails.dto~

Comment: @core114 can you update dataSource so that it can match your data don't copy your data if you cannot share it just update some rows in dataSource to match your data.

Comment: @core114 can you also update your [MWE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d9m4jn?file=index.js)

Comment: hi, I tried to added it, cant add stazkblitz to .dto file

Comment: you can copy some samples and add that to it.

Comment: Hi, Updated link here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d9m4jn?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

Create Sample `User` interface and `Group` interface for example

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Table, Input, Button, Space } from "antd";
import { ColumnsType } from "antd/es/table";
import { SearchOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./styles.css";

interface User {
  key: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
}

interface Group {
  key: number;
  some: string;
  user: User;
}

const data: Group[] = [
  {
    key: 1,
    some: "foo",
    user: {
      key: 9,
      name: "John Brown",
      age: 32,
      address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park"
    }
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    some: "bar",
    user: {
      key: 3,
      name: "Joe Black",
      age: 42,
      address: "London No. 1 Lake Park"
    }
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    some: "baz",
    user: {
      key: 10,
      name: "Jim Green",
      age: 32,
      address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
    }
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    some: "text",
    user: {
      key: 21,
      name: "Jim Red",
      age: 32,
      address: "London No. 2 Lake Park"
    }
  }
];

interface AppState {
  searchText: string;
  searchedColumn: string;
}

interface AppProps {}

export default class App extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  state = {
    searchText: "",
    searchedColumn: ""
  };
  searchInput: any;

  getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex: string) => ({
    filterDropdown: ({
      setSelectedKeys,
      selectedKeys,
      confirm,
      clearFilters
    }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={(node) => {
            this.searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])
          }
          onPressEnter={() =>
            this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)
          }
          style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: "block" }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: (filtered: any) => (
      <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />
    ),
    onFilter: (value: any, record: any) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        ? JSON.stringify(record[dataIndex])
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase())
        : "",
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible: boolean) => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select(), 100);
      }
    },
    render: (text: string, record: any, index: any) => {
      return JSON.stringify(record[dataIndex]);
    }
  });

  handleSearch = (selectedKeys: any, confirm: any, dataIndex: any) => {
    confirm();
    this.setState({
      searchText: selectedKeys[0],
      searchedColumn: dataIndex
    });
  };

  handleReset = (clearFilters: any) => {
    clearFilters();
    this.setState({ searchText: "" });
  };

  render() {
    const columns: ColumnsType<Group> = [
      {
        key: "some",
        title: "Some",
        dataIndex: "some",
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps("some")
      },
      {
        key: "user",
        title: "User",
        dataIndex: "user",
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps("user")
      }
    ];
    return <Table<Group> columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
  }
}
```

Here Working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-dawn-lqyxg?file=/src/App.tsx)